# Bash script: Using grep to find a string that is also an option

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I call the program with the text I want to find, so `programname '-r'`

Then, within the script I have `text="${1}"`

```
find . -r -name "hi.*" -exec grep -l "${text}" {} \;
```

The second half of that simplifies to `grep -l -r` and it waits for another input

How do I specify that `-r` is the string to be found, and not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSIX standard mandates that `grep` support an option `-e` that forces the following argument to be treated as a regular expression, rather than another option.

```
find . -r -name "hi.*" -exec grep -l -e "$text" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `--` after the `-l` [or your last valid option]. That stops option processing in `grep` so that your text will be interpreted as a string to search for and not an option:

```
find . -r -name "hi.*" -exec grep -l -- "${text}" {} \;
```

Comment: GNU `grep` uses `--` to signify the end of options; not all versions of `grep` will.

Comment: @chepner Based on the question tags: linux, bash, grep we can assume GNU grep for the probable answer. I've used "--" for a number of different commands in similar situations.